# Change progress bar from marquee to continuous mid code

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, progress-bar

I am using VS 2010 (visual basic) and am wondering how to change the progress bar `loader` from marquee (what I want it to initially be) to continuous (so that I can display actual progress when it starts doing things) mid-code on the `MyBase.Load` part of a window, after a delay between processes.

I tried using `loader.style.continuous()` it gives me an error saying it isn't a method.

When using the auto-correct in Visual Studio it corrects to `ProgressBarStyle.continuous()` but it just gives a different error.

How can I accomplish this? -Thanks

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: `loader.style.continuous()` keeps spitting out an error saying it isn't a method. When I try using the auto-fix thing it just gives a different error. It corrects to `ProgressBarStyle.continuous()` but still doesn't work.

Comment: Try `loader.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Continuous`

Comment: XD Thanks! You should add that as the answer so I can select it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(From comments) You need to set the `Style` property which is of the type `ProgressBarStyle` - an `Enum`.

`loader.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Continuous`